# c# Получение строки Ошибки

Tags: c#

```
try
{
.........
......Код
.........
}
catch
{ 
    Как получить номер строки кода, на которой произошла ошибка?
}
```

Comment: [StackTrace class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В `.NET` есть класс [StackTrace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace), который позволяет "выдрать" из ошибки все необходимое.
Делается это примерно так:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception("Некая ошибка");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"StackTrace: {e.StackTrace}\n\n");

        var trace = new StackTrace(e, true);

        foreach (var frame in trace.GetFrames())
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.AppendLine($"Файл: {frame.GetFileName()}");
            sb.AppendLine($"Строка: {frame.GetFileLineNumber()}");
            sb.AppendLine($"Столбец: {frame.GetFileColumnNumber()}");
            sb.AppendLine($"Метод: {frame.GetMethod()}");

            Console.WriteLine(sb);
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Пояснения:

- `throw new Exception("Некая ошибка");` - Тестовая ошибка.
- `catch (Exception e)` - Получаем информацию об ошибке.
- `Console.WriteLine($"StackTrace: {e.StackTrace}\n\n");` - выводим StackTrace в виде строки (такой нам генерирует Exeption).
- `var sb = new StringBuilder();` - Собираем необходимые данные в билдер.
- `Console.WriteLine(sb);` - Выводим.

Вывод:

```
StackTrace:    в VFS.Program.Main(String[] args) в D:\Projects\Other\TestedApps\VFS\Program.cs:строка 100


Файл: D:\Projects\Other\TestedApps\VFS\Program.cs
Строка: 100
Столбец: 13
Метод: Void Main(System.String[])
```

[image: Code]

---

Если вы хотите получать такие данные без студии, то не забудьте о наличие `.pdb` файла!

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            int i = 3;
            while (true)
                Console.WriteLine(i / --i); // тут будет деление на 0
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

В .NET Core мне выводит, что ошибка на 13 строке, там находится `Console.WriteLine()`

`at ConsoleApp1.Program.Main() in D:\Projects\C#\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 13`

Comment: И где вы тут получаете "номер строки кода, на которой произошла ошибка?" Берите быстрей из комментария под вопросом класс, выведите номер и редактируйте ответ, получите +, а так, уж извините, ответ совсем не про то...

Comment: Ну учитывая, что у автора в catch не было прописано захвата исключения, то видимо он не понимает как работает catch. Номер строки кода получить в скомпилированном приложении - это как? Скомпилированные исполняемые файлы не содержат в себе исходный код, они не знают, что там у автора были за строки. Для такого придуман дебаггер и точки останова. Ну и просто нужно внутрь функций закладывать обработку исключений, по которым можно будет понять, где ошибка.

Comment: @FuManchu "exception.Message" слишком мало инфы дает. Лучше уж тогда "exception.ToString()"

Comment: Если с проектом вместе предоставлять еще и .pdb файл, то будет без проблем отображать всю информацию, как и при дебаге, используя класс `StackTrace`.

Comment: Я скорректировал ответ, мне выдало именно строчку, хотя может быть оно только в NET Core так работает