# Узнать название класса и метода

Tags: c#

Можно как то узнать название класса и метода ?

Возможно такие вещи как то иначе решаются...

Я хотел бы в блоке `catch` написать что то такое:

```
Debag.Writeline($"{Название класса} {Название метода} {ex.Message}")
```

Comment: @aepot спасибо, попробую так, просто что то боялся трассировки стека, оч много информации( Какой то `Task` чудит, а я не могу найти где это происходит(

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1102438/220553

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Зачем, если есть трассировка стека? И название класса, и метода и номер строки кода. `Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());` - и не надо мудрить.

А так имя класса не получится, а вот метода можно

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("My message");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{ex.GetType().Name} in method {ex.TargetSite}: {ex.Message}");
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

```
ArgumentException in method Void Main(System.String[]): My message
```

Тогда как `ex.ToString()` выдаст следующее

```
System.ArgumentException: My message
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Source\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 18
```

Согласитесь, удобнее? Именно трассировка стека - ваш спасательный круг при поиске источника исключения.

Comment: Спасибо! Значит так и буду отыскивать.